# popup modal ends up being just a "div" on the site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got something wrong in my js file that I can't pin down. There's a popup modal in there that has been fine for quite some time.  I recently changed the text, and the functionality is gone.  Instead of a modal popup I'm getting a simple  on the page, with no way to close it. I've been struggling with the code for quite some time and don't see what's wrong.

```
var docloch = document.location.href,
scree = [screen.availWidth,screen.availHeight],
thisVal="",
tAlign="left",
afterwhat="h3";

// ----------- modal for home page popup banner  -----------------------gigit
//if (docloch == "https://www.perfectmakeupmirrors.com/"){
if (document.cookie.indexOf("ad_stopper") ==-1){

    setTimeout(function(){
        document.cookie = "ad_stopper";
        if (scree[0] < 500) {
            var module_width="95%", ad_width="95%";
        } else {
            var module_width="50%", ad_width="90%";
        }   
        
        // Black Friday and following week deal - watch out of "Extended" in the text.
        /*$('#free_shipping_line').after('<div id="cyber_dialog" class="cyber_popup" style="width:'+ad_width+';position:relative;"><div style="text-align:center;height:auto;border:5px solid #9a9a9a;color:#ffffff;background-color:#000;display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;font-weight:bold;"><div style="width:auto"><img src="/images/5fb1af5dd0f4b.jpg" width="auto" height="36" style="margin-top:5px"><br><span style="font-size:2em;color:#00FF00">NOW EXTENDED! Save $89.90</span></div><a href="/mirror-image-helix-5x1x-chrome-black-vanity-mirror.html"><img src="/images/5f944f9d85e19.png" style="float:right;margin-right:20px" /></a></span><span style="font-size:1.6em">Buy any <a href="/mirrors-shop-by-brand/kimball-young-makeup-mirrors.html"><span style="font-size:1em;color:#3366FF">Kimball &amp; Young</span></a><span style="font-style:italic"> Lighted</span> mirror** <br/>and get this $94.90 <a href="/mirror-image-helix-5x1x-chrome-black-vanity-mirror.html"><span style="color:#3366FF">Mirror Image Vanity Mirror</span></a><br /> for <span class="style1" style="color:#00FF00;font-size:1.5em">$5.00</span> <br />Too good to be true? Yes, but it is TRUE.<br /></span><span style="font-size:1.2em">Put both Mirrors in the Shopping Cart.<br />At the <em>Checkout</em>, use Promo Code MIRROR5 - save $89.90.</span><br /><span tyle="font-size:.9em">**Closeouts not included.</span></div></div>'); */

     /*
         $('#free_shipping_line').after('<div id="cyber_dialog" class="cyber_popup" style="width:'+ad_width+';position:relative;"><div style="text-align:center;height:auto;border:5px solid #9a9a9a;color:#ffffff;background-color:#cc00ff;display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;margin-bottom:25px;font-weight:bold;"><span style="font-size:2em">Price Breakthrough + Free Shipping <br />Save up to 40% OFF!<br /></span><span style="font-size:1.6em">New Lower Pricing on<br/><a href="/mirrors-shop-by-brand/kimball-young-makeup-mirrors.html"><span style="font-size:1em">Kimball & Young</span></a> Vanity Mirrors**.<br /></span><span style="font-size:1.2em">No promo code.  Price shown on each Kimball & Young Vanity Mirror.</span><br /><span tyle="font-size:.9em">**Closeouts not included.</span></div>); */
 
         $('#free_shipping_line').after('<div style="position:relative;z-index:300;width:900px;text-align:center;height:auto;border:5px solid  #9a9a9a;color:#ffffff;background-color:#f00;display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;font-weight:bold;"><span style="font-size:2em;color:#0f0">Now! Save $89.90<br /><a href="/mirror-image-helix-5x1x-chrome-black-vanity-mirror.html"><img src="/images/5fce4d5834401.png" style="float:right;margin-right:20px" /></a></span><span style="font-size:1.6em">Buy any <a href="/mirrors-shop-by-brand/kimball-young-makeup-mirrors.html"><span style="font-size:1em">Kimball &amp; Young</span></a><span style="font-style:italic"> Lighted</span> mirror** <br/>and get this $94.90 <a href="/mirror-image-helix-5x1x-chrome-black-vanity-mirror.html">Mirror Image Vanity Mirror</a><br /> for <span class="style1" style="color:#00FF00;font-size:1.5em">$5.00</span>  <span style="color:#aaa;font-size:.8em">(shhh.. a great Christmas gift!)</span><br />Too good to be true? Yes, but it is TRUE.<br /></span><span style="font-size:1.2em">Put both Mirrors in the Shopping Cart.<br />At the <em>Checkout</em>, use Promo Code MIRROR<span style="font-size:1.23em">5</span> - save $89.90.</span><br /><span tyle="font-size:.9em">**Closeouts not included.</span></div>'); 
                                       


        /*  $('#free_shipping_line').after('<div id="cyber_dialog" class="cyber_popup" style="display:none;position:relative;text-align:center;width:825px;height:auto;border:5px solid #9a9a9a;color:#ffffff;background-color:#CC00FF;display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;font-size:1.6em;font-weight:bold;padding:7px">FREE 10x <span style="font-size:.85em">Pink Bling Vanity Mirror</span> + FREE Shipping<br /><a href="/pink-bling-10x1x-free-standing-makeup-mirror.html"><img src="https://www.perfectmakeupmirrors.com/images/5e9c97bfc3890.png" style="float:right;margin-top:-25"></a><ul style="font-size:.83em;text-align:left;margin:3px 0 0 120px;list-style-type:disclosure-closed"><li>Put a <a href="/mirrors-shop-by-brand/kimball-young-makeup-mirrors.html">Kimball & Young</a> <em><strong>LIGHTED</strong></em> Vanity Mirror** in the cart.</li><li>Put the <a href="/pink-bling-10x1x-free-standing-makeup-mirror.html">Pink Bling 10x Vanity Mirror</a> in the cart.</li><li>No Promo Code needed -  $44.90 is automatically deducted.</li></span></ul><div style="font-size:.7em;margin-top:8px">**No Closeouts. &nbsp;&nbsp;Need more than one? &nbsp;Place additional orders.</div></div>');  */

         /* $('#free_shipping_line').after('<div id="cyber_dialog" class="cyber_popup" style="display:none;position:relative;text-align:center;width:800px;height:172px;border:5px solid #9a9a9a;color:#ffffff;background-color:#9900ff;display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;font-size:1.6em;font-weight:bold;">$25.00 OFF + FREE Shipping when you buy<br />any LIGHTED Vanity Mirror**<br/>by <a href="/mirrors-shop-by-brand/kimball-young-makeup-mirrors.html">Kimball & Young</a> or <a href="/mirrors-shop-by-brand/electric-mirror.html">Electric Mirror</a><br/><strong>AND</strong> and any <a href="/skin-care?cat=144">Shunly Skincare</a> Product.<br/>Use Promo Code <span style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold">DEAL25</span><br />**<span style="font-size:11px">Closeouts not included.</div>'); */

      options = {
            type: 'popup',
            responsive: true,
            innerScroll: true,
            autoOpen: true,
            modalClass : "",

            title: "Save up to $222.30 with Kimball & Young Price Drops",
            clickableOverlay: true,
            buttons:[{
                text: $.mage.__('Close'),
                click: function(){
                    this.closeModal();
                }
            }]
        };
        $('#cyber_dialog').modal(options);
        $(".modal-inner-wrap").css({"max-width":module_width,"margin-top":"5%"});
    }, 1750);
};
```

Comment: Aren't you missing the `<div>` id (`cyber_dialog`)? `$('#free_shipping_line').after('<div id="cyber_dialog" ...`

Comment: I don't see where this is missing. Please point that out to me.

Comment: It is in the `setTimeout`, the only line starting with `$('#free_shipping_line').after('<div ...)` which is not commented.

Comment: Actually, I think the entire question will be removed as your problem was generated by a "typo" therefore the answer would hardly be beneficial to anybody else. Anyway, I am happy I could help. ;)

Comment: Yes, I agree with you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the comment, you are missing an `id` attribute; the line:

`$('#free_shipping_line').after('<div style="...">...</div>');`

should become `$('#free_shipping_line').after('<div id="cyber_dialog" style="...">...</div>');`